# Getting char from string its hex value

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

I currently get a string as a parameters in my method,
i would like to extract the char in the I index and get it's hex value.
Currently i'm doing :

```
temp = string[i]
binascii.hexlify(temp);
```

but i get an error :

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode the string to bytes:

```
binascii.hexlify(temp.encode('ascii'));
```

You'll need to pick a suitable encoding, one that can represent your text properly; I am presuming that your unicode characters fall in the 0-127 range here.

If you encode to a different encoding, the result will be a hex representation of that encoding. UTF-8 will use between 1 and 6 bytes per character for example.

Alternatively, you could use the [`ord()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) and format the result to hex:

```
format(ord(temp), 'x')
```

and it'll work with any unicode character. It'll use the Unicode code point for the hex representation, so between 1 and 4 bytes (the latter for `\Uabcdefgh` wide characters). Depending on your maximum character width, you may want to pad the bytes to prevent ambiguous code points; say you need to encode up to codepoint `\uffff` then you'll need to use 2 bytes for *every* codepoint, or 4 hex characters:

```
format(ord(temp), '04x')
```

Comment: Actually ASCII characters fall in the 0-127 range.

Comment: @kmkaplan: I didn't say that ASCII was in the 0-255 range, I said I presumed his data was in that range :-P But you are correct, byte values 128-255 won't encode to ASCII.

Comment: That's doing the job. Thanks !!